# MySQL: How to use Multi-SELECT in SELECT cluase?

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I have a table as this, name *aaa*:

```
year   month amount
1991   1     1.1
1991   2     1.2
1991   3     1.3
1991   4     1.4
1992   1     2.1
1992   2     2.2
1992   3     2.3
1993   4     2.4
```

I want a result like this:

```
year m1   m2   m3   m4
1991 1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4
1992 2.1  2.2  2.3  2.4
```

As a novice, I can't find a way out after hours searching and experiencing. I tried this but failed:

```
SELECT year,
(SELECT amount FROM aaa WHERE month=1) AS m1,
(SELECT amount FROM aaa WHERE month=2) AS m2,
(SELECT amount FROM aaa WHERE month=3) AS m3,
(SELECT amount FROM aaa WHERE month=4) AS m4
FROM aaa GROUP BY year;
```

Anyone could show me? or let me know where I can find an answer? Thx in advance.

or this:

```
SELECT year,
(SELECT amount FROM aaa m WHERE month=1 AND m.year=aaa.year) AS m1,
(SELECT amount FROM aaa m WHERE month=2 AND m.year=aaa.year) AS m2,
(SELECT amount FROM aaa m WHERE month=3 AND m.year=aaa.year) AS m3,
(SELECT amount FROM aaa m WHERE month=4 AND m.year=aaa.year) AS m4
FROM aaa GROUP BY year;
```

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: Solved the problem by GROUP_CONCAT & CASE SYNTAX like this: ' GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN month=2 THEN aaa.amount ELSE NULL END) AS m2'